# What else do I need to do to satisfy Apache working as a plain old media server?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, apache-2.4, permissions

I am trying to set up an Apache VirtualHost on an Ubuntu 13.10 EC2 instance that will serve up media documents from a directory old-school-style. There is an existing VirtualHost which is handling a ProxyPass well enough, and the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName media.ccachicago.org
    ServerAlias media.ccachicago.pragmatometer.com
    DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/ccachicago/media
    <Directory "/home/ubuntu/ccachicago/media">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        #Order deny,allow
        #Deny from all
        #Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>
    ServerAdmin CJSHayward@PObox.com
</VirtualHost>
```

media.ccachicago.pragmatometer.com/css/style.css is getting the following 403 error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) Server at media.ccachicago.pragmatometer.com Port 80
```

I've checked file permissions several ways, and as `nobody` I can cat /home/ubuntu/ccachicago/media/css/style.css, but I've only gotten a 403 on trying to access this VirtualHost. I've also checked that the `<Directory>` permissions above will allow media access to any client.

What else could I be doing that would stop the VirtualHost to serve up static media content as desired? The machine is a new Ubuntu 13.10 Amazon EC2 instance, and only has VirtualHosts, contents, etc. from the new project.

Comment: Does the edit mean you have an answer ?

Comment: Yes; I was giving the answer I found.

Comment: You should really provide an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to replace:

```
Order deny, allow
Deny from all
Allow from 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0 ::1/128
```

with:

```
Require all granted
```

from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992466/apache-permission-denied